# Attempting to insert an entity with an auto-incremented ID puts Entity Framework Core in a funky state

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I think I ran across an interesting problem with Entity Framework Core 5 while doing a unit test on SQL Server. My tables are set to cascade deletions.

I have a parent table that I inserted a row into. Everything went fine.

Now I specifically inserted an entity in the child table with a value for the column Id and the parent ID as foreign key. The insert failed as expected with error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'XXXXX' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Then things took a turn for the worse at that point.

I tried to delete the parent row. SQL Server yells at me that I still cannot insert into the child table while `IDENTITY_INSERT` is off. The same error I got with the invalid insert. I am surmising that the cascade deletion is kicking in but since I was not successful at inserting a row in the child table with the parent PK there should have been no issue.

Has anybody also run into such a problem before?

Comment: Are you using one and the same db context instance for these operations? Because even though the database insert fails, the child entity will still be marked for adding inside the db context change tracker, so may be `SaveChanges` is trying again to insert it *before* the delete command.

Comment: @IvanStoev, you are absolutely correct. After much digging I did realize that I was using the same db context. It took a while to find a solution because I am in a dependency injection context where the db context is injected by some services...so I had to play not only with the lifetime of the services that my unit test was using but also with the lifetime of the db context itself. 

The error goes away like magic if the context is different. Beautiful pointer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

I will accept @IvanStoev's answer. It was a db context problem. I was using the same context for both operations and the entity was still in the cache. Entity Framework attempted to add the entity before it deleted it.

Comment: If you don' t change the context, you have to detach the child entity from the context with

```context.Entry(yourentity).State = EntityState.Detached```

That way you can delete the parent entity without causing the framework to try and save the child entity.